# Annoying notification when trying to create a new page

Tags: pages, notifications

Whenever I try tomake a new page, I get an annoying block asking me so upgrade some plugin of some sort. Is there a way to get rid of this extremely annoying notification?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This notification is added by your theme. You can remove the upsell notices for this theme by hooking into the `ttfmake_is_plus` filter:

```
add_filter( 'ttfmake_is_plus', '__return_true' );
```

Comment: I did not realize it was a theme thing! Thank you! :)